# How to push the host availabilty slots into the calendar using php?

Tags: php

I am developing the normal event scheduling  calendar using php ,

HTML :

```html
<!-- calendar start -->
       <div class="book_sesin_clndr">
        <!-- calendar row start -->
        <div class="row clndr_hdr_row">
         <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-3"><p>PDT</p></div>
           <div class="col-xs-3"><p>SUN <br>5/31</p></div>
           <div class="col-xs-3"><p>MON <br>6/1</p></div>
           <div class="col-xs-3"><p>TUE <br>6/2</p></div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-3"><p>WED <br>6/3</p></div>
           <div class="col-xs-3"><p>THU <br>6/4</p></div>
           <div class="col-xs-3"><p>FRI <br>6/5</p></div>
           <div class="col-xs-3"><p>SAT <br>6/6</p></div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <!-- calendar row end -->

        <div class="clndr_cntnt">

         <!-- calendar row start -->
         <div class="row clndr_row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3"><p>9am</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <!-- calendar row end -->

         <!-- calendar row start -->
         <div class="row clndr_row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3"><p>10am</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
             <a href="#" class="slt_time_btn">10.00 - 10.30 <br>Available</a>
             <a href="#" class="slt_time_btn">10.30 - 11.00 <br>Available</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
             <a href="#" class="slt_time_btn">10.00 - 10.30 <br>Available</a>
             <a href="#" class="slt_time_btn">10.30 - 11.00 <br>Available</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
             <a href="#" class="slt_time_btn">10.00 - 10.30 <br>Available</a>
             <a href="#" class="slt_time_btn">10.30 - 11.00 <br>Available</a>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
             <a href="#" class="slt_time_btn">10.00 - 10.30 <br>Available</a>
             <a href="#" class="slt_time_btn">10.30 - 11.00 <br>Available</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
             <a href="#" class="slt_time_btn">10.00 - 10.30 <br>Available</a>
             <a href="#" class="slt_time_btn">10.30 - 11.00 <br>Available</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
             <a href="#" class="slt_time_btn">10.00 - 10.30 <br>Available</a>
             <a href="#" class="slt_time_btn">10.30 - 11.00 <br>Available</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
             <a href="#" class="slt_time_btn">10.00 - 10.30 <br>Available</a>
             <a href="#" class="slt_time_btn">10.30 - 11.00 <br>Available</a>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <!-- calendar row end -->
```

I have the slots data like this format :

response from host availability endpoint will look like  this.

{start: "2020-06-10 14:00:00", end: "2020-06-10 14:30:00"}

{start: "2020-06-10 14:30:00", end: "2020-06-10 15:00:00"}

so that host have available slots on

june 6th 14:00 to 14:30

june 6th 14:30 to 15:00 
etc.,

these slots have to show in calendar in that date(june 6th)

$response have all available slots as i said before like JSON

How can I push that into the custom calendar using php .  Please provide me the resources or any suggestions.

Comment: Since we have no idea how your custom calendar is built we cannot suggest anything. Give us more information please

Comment: It is just like normal scheduling calendar through slots on that day. Okay i will edit that to normal calendar event scheduling management. @ADyson

Comment: Just give some idea or code pls @ADyson please yarr

Comment: There's no such thing as a "normal" event scheduling calendar. There could be 100 different ways to do it. Unless we understand the structure of your specific implementation then we cannot help you

Comment: Can i share the mockup page is it helpful . I just have this data only mockuo and this idea. So Is it helpful can i share the mockup of my calendar ?@ADyson

Comment: We need the HTML markup of the calendar layout in order to understand where to locate the slots, what element to use to represent them etc

Comment: P.s. have you considered in using a ready made calendar layout such as fullCalendar? It would be easier than designing your own. It can get very complicated quite quickly.

Comment: see i added the calendar code i need to insert that time slots into the particular date. @ADyson

Comment: Looks like you need to add some more divs then. What is the issue...do you need to know how to make a div, or is your problem with how to find the right place in the layout?

Comment: @ADyson I added the link once check and pls help me with the PHP file for that. If you saw this msg please once upvote this comment i can understand that u read

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Please answer it. And please don't remove the code from your question. I added it back.

Comment: I just want to push the slots to the particular date yarr Using PHP . @ADyson That's it

Comment: $tbl.='<tr>';

for($day=1; $day<=7; $day++)
{
 $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($curYear."W".$curWeek.$day));
 $time = date('H:i:s');
 
 //Here we need to check available slots for that day or not
 // If any slots available add to calendar in that date
 
 //Loop the $response data here
 
 // if start date in $response match with $date (line 71)
    
    // Push slot to day
    
    $start = $response['start_date'];
    
    $tbl.='<li class="sltli avlslt">'.date('H:i',strtotime($start)).'</li>';  
 
}
$tbl.='</tr>  PHP code can u provide the code for the comments @ADyson ps

Comment: @ADyson https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336953/how-to-pushing-the-slots-to-the-respective-dates-usign-php check this link